# "Unable to render HTML. Unable to create WebBrowser. COM error 80040154. Class not registered" error when using ABCpdf component

Tags: asp.net, docker, com, containers, abcpdf

I am using ABCpdf (version 12.5.0.4) for generating pdf in my ASP.Net Web Form application running in a docker container. When I try to do Doc.AddImageUrl, I am getting below error, any help would be much appreciated.
"Unable to render HTML. Unable to create WebBrowser.
COM error 80040154. Class not registered"

I was earlier using mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 as my base image in order to build application image. After encountering this error, I thought cut down version of Windows will not fully support ABCpdf operations, So I changed my base image to mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 and built the application image, which also didn't help.
Same application is working fine if I deploy it in windows server(working fine in dev machine as well) but not on container
Expectation: Successful generation of PDF and its rendering in new browser tab.

Comment: You should contact the ABCpdf vendor